# how to make a proxy for both nodejs apps and apache tomcat apps with nginx by different domain name?

Tags: node.js, tomcat, nginx

i have a domain name , for example abc.com and only one virtual machine in ali cloud with public ip 112.70.230.217 , but at the same time i want to run personal blog "ghost"(a blog project of nodejs) and an java web application which on tomcat. so i create resolves "blog.abc.com" for my blog and "app.abc.com" for the tomcat application and "res.abc.com" for the static resource that my tomcat application will need.

1. i move my app.war as $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT.war and make tomcat with default setting (8080 port) and start the tomcat.
2. the static resource is in /data/resource/*
3. for the "ghost" apps, it's default access address is localhost:2368.

**my question is** : how to set the nginx server config these three domain addresses link to these three (#1,#2,#3)

and i had try the following setting, but all of three domain addresses link to the #1

Comment: ghost.conf:

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name blog.abc.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        }
}

Comment: app.conf: server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.abc.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
}

server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  resource.abc.com;

        location /resoure/ {
                root   /data/resource/;
                autoindex on;
                autoindex_exact_size off;
                autoindex_localtime on;
        }
}

Comment: both files had been included in nginx.conf, i can confirm that no extra server block setting had been included

Comment: and all the domain had been set to the some ip address (for example 112.70.230.217), which i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that when using the script "include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;" in nginx.conf, the new conf file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ will over write the config block.

take this for example , i have two file a.conf and b.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/, first nginx will load server block in a.conf then when it will load b.conf. when nginx found there is a block definition, it will overwrite previous one. i don't know if it's correct, but when i put the conf in one file, it will work in a way.